# 500 (Internal Server Error) Laravel Delete Method

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to delete using ajax in laravel but it shows me error like 500 (Internal Server Error), i know its a token error but i am passing a token too still getting same error. without ajax i am able to delete a record.

[image]

**Route:**

```
Route::get('users/delete/{id}','UserController@destroy');
```

**HTML**

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger js-sweetalert"  data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" data-id="{{$obj->id}}" title="Delete" data-type="confirm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
    <script>
    $(function () {
    $('.js-sweetalert').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var type = $(this).data('type');
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var token = $(this).data("token");
        var url = $(this).attr("data-link");
        if (type === 'confirm') {
            showConfirmMessage(id,token,url);
        }
      });
    }); 
    function showConfirmMessage(id,token,url) {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#dc3545",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }, function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://localhost:82/reports.laravel.com/public/users/delete/"+id,
            data: {
                id: id,
                _token: token
                 },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("it Work");
                if(data==true){
                    swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
                }

            }         
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function destroy($id)
        {
            $user = User::find($id);
            $deleted = $user->delete();
            if($deleted){
                return true;
            }
        }
}
```

**Log:**

```
[2018-09-19 09:58:18] local.ERROR: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given. {"userId":1,"email":"ansari@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), \"boolean\" given. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\symfony\\http-foundation\\Response.php:394)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Response.php(45): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response->setContent(true)
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\symfony\\http-foundation\\Response.php(202): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->setContent(true)
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(747): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response->__construct(true)
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(719): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::toResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), true)
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(679): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), true)
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\IsAdmin.php(21): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): App\\Http\\Middleware\\IsAdmin->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate.php(43): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#13 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(75): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#17 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#20 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(681): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#32 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(656): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(622): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#34 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(611): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#42 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#48 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#50 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#51 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#52 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#53 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#54 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#55 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
eports.laravel.com\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#56 {main}
"}
```

Comment: What does your log file say `/storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: 1. You don't check if user exists, and you should - perhaps you are trying to delete a user that is not there (or can't be found using find() - e.g. when you use `SoftDelete` trait, `find()` method assumes only non-deleted users (i.e. those entities that have a date "deleted_at" set to NULL.
 2. If you submit this request (with type "DELETE") to this URL: `http://localhost:82/reports.laravel.com/public/users/delete/ + id` and with query params using Postman (or other tool for request debugging) - what's the result?

Comment: in post man every thing working correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Change accordingly :***

**Route:**

```
Route::delete('users/delete/{id}','UserController@destroy');
```

**Controller:**

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function destroy($id)
        {
            $deleted = User::find($id)->delete();
            if($deleted){
                return true;
            }
        }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: "http://localhost:82/reports.laravel.com/public/users/delete/"+id,
            data: {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            "id": id
            }
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("it Work");
                if(data==true){
                    swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
                }

            }         
        });
```

Comment: GET http://localhost:82/reports.laravel.com/public/users/delete?id=22&_token=t8ZbANjtB3Pil6OGTdfD3ze3aquk6HGN6niW8HnK 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Add your token in data like this if it won't  then please show the error

```
"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[2018-09-19 09:58:18] local.ERROR: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given. {"userId":1,"email":"ansari@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), \"boolean\" given. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\
```

eports.laravel.com\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Response.php:394)
[stacktrace]

Regarding the error it's because you are returning a boolean `true` in your controller, because you are trigger the `UserController@destroy` controller with an ajax call, I will suggest you to do this

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        if($request->ajax()) {
            $user->delete();
            return response()->json(['deleted' =>> true, 'user' => $user]);
        } else {
            $user->delete();
            return response()->setContent(true);
        }
    }
}
```